# How can we find the exact Translation vector(with exact scaling, not with unit norm) from fundamental matrix

Tags: computer-vision

I'm trying to obtain the 3D metric reconstruction of the points I have in two different views of my scene by means of a pair of cameras (a stereo system).

To do so, I did calibrate the cameras, estimate the fundamental matrix and obtained an estimate of the essential matrix. Now, in Hartley&Zisserman "Multiple View Geometry in CV" book, I see that to any given E, they correspond 4 canonical cameras pairs, of which only one reconstructs as the "actual" stereo configuration.

But the problem is that the norm of translation vector is 1. I need the exact translation vector.

Answer (score 0):

If you jointly calibrated the cameras of your stereo rig, then the translation vector is an output of that, expressed in the same units as the geometry specification of the calibration object you used.

If you didn't, then you do not yet have any information about the scale of your scene. You can recover it by reconstructing (via stereo) an object with known dimensions.